# How to convert bold to strong, italic to emphasis on pasted text?

Tags: wysiwyg, input-formats, theming

I'm using [Paste Format](https://drupal.org/project/pasteformat) to clean up all text pasted into CKEditor (setup with WYSIWYG API), and it does a great job at this. Both the text format for users, and the text format that pasteformat uses for cleanup are setup with [WYSIWYG Filter](https://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_filter).

Content pasted from Word or OpenOffice usually contains b and i tags rather than `<strong>` and `<em>`. Is there a way to convert `<b>` to `<strong>` and `<i>` to `<em>`? Ideally this would happen during the paste action (e.g. with the pasteformat text filter?) so the correct tags will be saved to the database, but converting the tags upon display would also be acceptable.

Any clean way to accomplish this?

Comment: http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/2550 - if you usw WYSIWYG module with CKEditor 3.4 or newer, it should happen automagically. Not an answer, just a note.

Comment: I had actually stumbled upon that ticket as well, but it's about being able to make each individual <b> into <strong> via the editor button - this does indeed work. What I'd like is all underlying <b> tags to be converted to <strong> automatically, either before saving or upon display, so I don't have to manually do this for every occurrence.

Comment: That's why I posted it only as a comment and upvoted your question.

Comment: Whoever is downvoting, care to explain please?